# Make discord.py bot send messages outside event loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a list of discord.py bots like [bot1, bot2, bot2]
every bots are started and put into an event loop

but how can I make one bot send messages outside commands and events?

I expected that I can make one bot send messages from an another function

Answer (score 0):

You can add a coroutine to the event loop manually, but you can't do something with the bot outside the event loop. If you want something to run when the bot is started / while the bot is running, you can use
the [`on_ready`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_ready) event.